# Need to calculate count of child table rows based on same key between Master and Child table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Looking for some optimize query to get "Count" (same occurrence of  MastId of @tblMaster table into @tblChild table.

```
Declare @tblMaster Table (MastId INT, MastDesc VARCHAR(10))
Insert Into @tblMaster Values(1, 'M1'),(2, 'M22')

Declare @tblChild Table (ChildId INT, MastId INT, ChildDesc VARCHAR(10))
Insert Into @tblChild Values(100, 1, 'M1'),(101, 1, 'M2'),(102, 1, 'M3'),(103, 2, 'M22')
```

In real scenario both table having 100K+ records. Please suggest!!!

Output should be,

[image]

Comment: Can you show sample data in both table,except for master ad child we don't have any idea on your question

Comment: sorry, now sample data added, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select mastid,mastdesc,count(*) as cnt
from
master m
join
child c
on c.mastid=m.mastid
group by m.mastid,m.mastdesc
```

Update based on comment  :

100 K records is not very big deal,Group by can perform well if your data is indexed correctly..

Say for example,if you have Primary key on master mastid column and another primary key on child mastid col,i don't see an issue with query not performing better..

please run the query and update/ask a  new question with

1.Schema of tables involved
2.Actual execution plan as xml

if you think query runs slowly

Comment: Is "group by" is best optimized as I having 100K + records in each table

Comment: I agree that, but I have lots of tables on Join and each column I need to put in Group By. anyways thanks for solution and I will see on performance side. Thanks!